# Can I add multiple columns in MFC CListBox?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, clistbox

I have a dialog with a `CListBox` .I have to add 3 Columns in this list box.
*Is there any way to have several different columns in `CListBox` ?*
Or *Can `CListCtrl` help in this regard?*

Comment: Yes, that is what the distinction between a CListBox and CListCtrl is - one is for a single list of selectable items, the other is for tabular data.

Comment: Forest And the Trees: So do i have to use ClistCtrl . Is there any particular option for this multicolumn ?

Comment: Yuu can "simulate" a multicolumn CListBox by setting the listbox control's "Use Tabstops" property to TRUE. If you do so, you can insert strings containing tabs ('\t') as column limiter. Use CListBox::SetTabStops to set the width of the columns. But I'd rather suggest using CListCtrl instead of CListBox although it is more complicated to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Listbox has list of items in 1 column, a list-control can have zero or more columns.
- Natively, listbox does not have icon attached to it, list control has.
- List control has "header control" on top of it, which can be used to arrange and/or sort the items in columns.
- List Control (also know as report control) can have 4 or more view types (depending on OS) - icon, small icon, details/report, list and thumbnail.

The windows explorer file view (right side) is list control, fonts in Fonts dialog box is listbox.

Source : http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?358739-CListBox-and-CListCtrl.

use `CListCtrl::InsertColumn` to add new column.

- [here is the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz5b6131%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [here is a example](http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Visual_CPP/MFC_CListCtrl_InsertColumnItem.html)